# Validação de ancora para download

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

[image: foto do formulário para download]

Seguinte, preciso fazer a validação desse formulário de forma que só depois que a pessoa cadastrar ela consiga baixar o arquivo.
Com a tag  já consigo ter essa validação mas consegui colocar para fazer o download apenas com a tag  "ancora".

```
<section id="e-book">
    <header>
        <h3>Baixe nosso e-book</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<p>
    </header>
    <form id="for-banner" class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName2"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Nome Completo" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail2"></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2"    placeholder="E-mail Corporativo" required>
        </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/e-book/teste-ebook.pdf" download id="btn-ebook" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Download</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: E qual foi o *script* em JavaScript que pensou em utilizar?

Comment: na verdade pensei melhor aqui, o button faz isso aqui já, e verifica se o e-mail já está cadastrado no banco, preciso saber se a tag <button> do html tem como fazer download também igual essa tag <a>

Answer (score 1):

Se ela vai cadastrar, quer dizer que você vai ter um back envolvido, tendo isso em mente, basta você mandar uma `flag` de retorno e verificar, Ex:

```js
document.getElementById('btn-ebook').onclick = function(){
   // Aqui teria seu ajax, ex utilizando axios
   axios.post('SUA URL', {
      // PARAMS
   })
   .then(response => {
      // vamos supor que sua api tenha retornado o ok, e a URL
      if(response.status == 1){
        window.open(response.url, "_SELF")
      }else{
        alert('Você precisa se cadastrar antes')
      }
   })
   .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
   })
}
```

```html
<section id="e-book">
    <header>
        <h3>Baixe nosso e-book</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<p>
    </header>
    <form id="for-banner" class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName2"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Nome Completo" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail2"></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2"    placeholder="E-mail Corporativo" required>
        </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" download id="btn-ebook" class="btn btn-default">Download</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

E dessa forma, você teria sua validação.

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal consegui resolver de outra forma ao invés de baixar o e-book coloquei para acessar ele online com o seguinte cóigo:

`<section id="e-book">
    <header>
        <h3>Acesse nosso e-book</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<p>
    </header>
    <form method="post" action="images/Instalação do Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express.pdf" download id="for-banner" class="form-inline" target="_blank">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName2"></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="ipaddress" id="ipaddress" value="<?= $user_ip; ?>">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" name="nome2" placeholder="Nome Completo" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail2"></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" name="email2"  placeholder="E-mail Corporativo" required>
      </div>
    <div>
        <button id="btn-ebook" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            acessar agora
        </button>
    </div>
    </form>
</section>`

Dessa forma o usuário só conseguirá acessar o e-book se fizer o cadastro. Obrigado a todos.